# How to combine same memecheck error in valgrind suppression file into one

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks, profiling, valgrind

I am writing a suppression file for valgrind. I used ‘**--gen-suppressions=all’** option to generate the suppression file. I see there are multiple entries for same errors and I would like to combine them into one generic entry. Here is an example:-

```
{
   suppression 1
   Memcheck:Addr8
   fun:_ZNK19MultiInputInterfaceI19gpccs2allresp_pri_tE9getPacketEv
   fun:_ZNK19MultiInputInterfaceI19gpccs2allresp_pri_tE4peekERS0_
   fun:_ZN7PriRespI19gpccs2allresp_pri_t23all2ringlocal_pri_err_tE12PriInterfaceEv
   fun:_ZN2tc9handlePriEv
   fun:_ZN6Tasker14MethodFunctionI2tcEclEv
   fun:_ZN7sc_core15sc_spawn_objectIN6Tasker14MethodFunctionI2tcEEE9semanticsEv
   fun:semantics
   fun:_ZN7sc_core16sc_thread_cor_fnEPv
   obj:xxx/test.so
   obj:xxx/test.so
}

{
   suppression 2
   Memcheck:Addr8
   fun:_ZNK19MultiInputInterfaceI19gpccs2allresp_pri_tE4peekERS0_
   fun:_ZN7PriRespI19gpccs2allresp_pri_t23all2ringlocal_pri_err_tE12PriInterfaceEv
   fun:_ZN2tc9handlePriEv
   fun:_ZN6Tasker14MethodFunctionI2tcEclEv
   fun:_ZN7sc_core15sc_spawn_objectIN6Tasker14MethodFunctionI2tcEEE9semanticsEv
   fun:semantics
   fun:_ZN7sc_core16sc_thread_cor_fnEPv
   obj:xxx/test.so
   obj:xxx/test.so
}
```

I added following entry to combine these suppression:-

```
{
   addr8_suppression
   Memcheck:Addr8
   ...
   obj:xxx/test.so
   obj:xxx/test.so
}
```

Unfortunately it didn’t work for me. Can you please help me get the correct syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear why it does not work. On a small test, a similar suppression entry works. I suggest you rerun with -d -d -d -d. With debug log level 4, valgrind produces some detailed tracing of error suppression matching. That might explain why it does not work. If that does not clarify, file a bug on valgrind bugzilla.